# Cleaning Titan base leads to an timeout exception (Backend = Hbase)

Tags: hbase, titan

I am trying to clean my titan database and leading to an exception.
I guess my database is big that it hits timeout however, how i can configure this in titan then. I using Hbase as storage backend.
This is my code that returns exception;
Titan Version: 0.4.4

```
g.shutdown();
TitanCleanup.clear(g);

Exception in thread "main" com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanException: Unexpected exception during backend operation
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.execute(BackendOperation.java:67)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.util.TitanCleanup.clear(TitanCleanup.java:32)
    at TitanMain.main(TitanMain.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerTimeoutException: 106728ms passed since the last invocation, timeout is currently set to 60000
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AbstractClientScanner$1.hasNext(AbstractClientScanner.java:44)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager.clearStorage(HBaseStoreManager.java:358)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.clearStorage(Backend.java:465)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.util.TitanCleanup$1.call(TitanCleanup.java:35)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.util.TitanCleanup$1.call(TitanCleanup.java:32)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation.execute(BackendOperation.java:62)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerTimeoutException: 106728ms passed since the last invocation, timeout is currently set to 60000
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.next(ClientScanner.java:283)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AbstractClientScanner$1.hasNext(AbstractClientScanner.java:41)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.UnknownScannerException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.UnknownScannerException: Name: -3465920678372616028
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.next(HRegionServer.java:2625)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor28.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Server.call(WritableRpcEngine.java:323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseServer$Handler.run(HBaseServer.java:1434)

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.RemoteExceptionHandler.decodeRemoteException(RemoteExceptionHandler.java:96)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.call(ScannerCallable.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.call(ScannerCallable.java:42)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ServerCallable.withRetries(ServerCallable.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.next(ClientScanner.java:274)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: What version of Titan are you using?

Comment: I using 0.4.4 version.

Comment: thanks, moved comment to an answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerTimeoutException: 106728ms passed since the last invocation, timeout is currently set to 60000` @ HBaseStoreManager.java:358 means that it took ~107 seconds to delete a single row from HBase.  This is an absurdly long time for a single `HTable.delete` call.  Is something up with your cluster or client?  You can see the code in question here: https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/blob/0.4.4/titan-hbase/src/main/java/com/thinkaurelius/titan/diskstorage/hbase/HBaseStoreManager.java#L358

Comment: Shouldn't be because this is a dev cluster but i have indexing can it be the cause ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have restarted and now it can do clear operation.
So strange but its working now.